# Import errors for ThreeJS in vue-test-utils with Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, jestjs

I am trying to make my jest tests (used for a VueJS SPA) work since I integrated Three.js in one of my components, but I'm having some trouble. Everything works when I run the app, but tests crash with the error:

```
/Users/Whomever/FE/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import {
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I know that the source of the error is from the OrbitControls, but I can't manage to get around this. I have tried to import /js instead of /jsm in my component, but then I get the error saying that "THREE is not defined". Also, the thing I least understand is the fact that this single component (which is four children layers deep from the App.vue file) crashes every test, even all the components that don't use Three.js at all.

I have also tried to set THREE globally in the main Vue definition, without success. Here is how my component file is coded:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import * as THREE from "three";
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "Some3DComponent",
  components: {}
  data: () => ({
    displayModes: [],
    viewWidth: 100,
    viewHeight: 100,
    modelClickableElements: null,
    has3dModel: false,
    ground: null,
    animationFrame: null,
    editorMode: null,
    renderGround: true,
    scales: null
  }),
//Rest of the code that calls THREE and OrbitControls

    });
```

Finally I have also tried to import THREE in the index.html file, no success. Now I'm running out of options.

The problems began only since using Three.js, all tests were functional before that.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not import OrbitControls from the examples folder. This is a custom function.

Try copy/paste the example code you need to a new TypeScript class into your project. Then you should be able to import it correctly. Beware they probably both import THREE so you might have context issues.